# PHP - download file from other server and transmt same in parallel to user

Tags: php, web, download

I have a problem mentioned below:

There will be multiple servers like a.com, b.com, b1.com and so on.
The user will always logon to a.com and request for a file which would be present on any of the b.com, b1.com etc server. All fiels are present on servers with names starting from "b".

The application will connect to b1.com and find the file.
Now I want a way to download the file from b1.com without the user knowing that it is actually coming from b1.com. Is there a way that the file can be directly downloaded from b server to user desktop/pc? Or is there any way that while the file is being downloaded from "b" to "a", I can start the file transfer from "a" to "user"

I dont want to first downlaod the complete file from b to a and then a to user as it will double up the transfer time which will impact performance when file is large.

Any solutions in mind for this?? I am using PHP on server side. Any other solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) or [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to connect to your b servers, send headers to your client indicating the file type to trigger a download, then in a loop to download the file 8 KB at a time using [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), and using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) (`ob_flush()`) flush the 8 KB to the user, and iterate until the file is finished downloading.

**OR**

to avoid all that, you can look into using Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) module.

Comment: You can use stream_copy_to_stream instead of fread/fwrite loop. But like you said, proxy is way better :)